# Check if all letters of string are contained in list of letters in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Scrabble valid word checker function in Python. I need to see if the list contains all the letters in the word, but once I match a letter I cannot use it again. So if my word is 'test' and my list is ['t', 'a', 'e', 's'] that should return False since I need 2 t's.

Here is my idea:

```
def validWord(word, letterList):
  for x in word:
    if x in letterList:
      letterList = letterList.remove(x)
    else:
      return False
  return True
```

However I get this error when I compile it:
TypeError: arument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Now I am guessing that the "if x in letterList" only can run once and not iterate. So now I was hoping someone could give me a push in the right direction. This is just for fun on my part, I was going to use this to create a "Words with Friends Cheater" and show my friends.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.remove` returns `None` and you are assigning it to `letterList`. On the next iteration, it becomes `if x in None`, where `in` operator tries to iterate `None` and fails with that error. So, change

```
letterList = letterList.remove(x)
```

to

```
letterList.remove(x)
```

You can solve this problem like this

```
from collections import Counter

def validWord(word, letterList):
    word2, word1 = Counter(word), Counter(letterList)
    return all(word2[k] <= word1.get(k, 0) for k in word2)

print validWord("test", ["t", "a", "e", "s"])  # False
print validWord("test", ["t", "e", "t", "s"])  # True
```

Comment: Oh duh! Now I got it. Thanks for the quick help!